# Problems by removing button border effects

Tags: css

How can i disable this:
[image]

I was working with this half hour. Can't find who places these borders. Button is transparent. I've tried doing:

```
input[type="submit"]:active,
input[type="submit"]:focus {
    -moz-outline-style: none!important;
    outline:none!important;
    outline:0!important;
}
```

Still nothing..

Comment: Have you tried removing border, and not just outline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like a shadow to remove a shadow you can do:

```
webkit-box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
```

and in case it's a border just try

```
border: 0px;
```

Comment: Nice, if it worked you can mark my answer as solved!